# MySQL Compare prices

Tags: mysql

I am struggeling with creating a price comparison table with multiple suppliers.

The table has the following columns - lets call it table1:

```
|name   |partnumber |supplier  |cost 
CD      11A          West       10.11
CD      11A          East       10.00
USB     BBB          North      125.01
USB     BBB          West       101.10
```

What I would like to achieve is for table1 to show the following:

```
|name   |partnumber |supplier  |cost 
CD      11A          East       10.00
USB     BBB          West       101.10
```

Result/difference being: The table would only show the colums related to the supplier that has the product at its cheapest price.

Is there anyone who would mind giving me a hand with it? It has been doing my head in.

Alternatively; I have also created another table with a price column for each supplier, but that isn't standardising the database and it wouldn't make for a well written query or performance.

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain, which columns can identify a product.

Answer (score 0):

this query what you need

```
SELECT a.name , a.partnumber , a.supplier , a.cost FROM table1 a JOIN (
  SELECT name , partnumber , MIN(cost) cost
  FROM table1 
  GROUP BY name , partnumber
) b ON a.name = b.name AND a.cost = b.cost AND a.partnumber = b.partnumber
```

you need to group the result by(name and partnumber) and find the minimum cost for each group

Comment: I would group by partnumber, that's probably more reliable.

Comment: @Noob sorry i didn't get you. how could I use `HAVING` ?

Comment: My bad sorry @Ali

Comment: Thank you @Ali, this seems to be just what I needed. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Johnny happy to help :)

Comment: Why would you group by `partnumber`, but not select it and use in the ON clause?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel my mistake

Comment: I'd say it's OPs mistake not defining a "group". Your mistake is to answer an unclear question. (I don't say I don't do that too (sometimes) :-))

Comment: @Ali, if I were to throw stock into the mix, that e.g. cost was cheapest with East, but they did not have it in stock, but West does, so West takes East' place in the table although they weren't the cheapest?