# Another MySQL price & stock comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a follow-up question from my original post ([MySQL price & stock comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625504/mysql-price-stock-comparison))

Lets say I have TABLE1 containing the following columns;

TABLE1 (raw data, no modifications done)

```
|item   |partnumber  |supplier |stock  |cost 
 CD      11A          West      11      10.11
 CD      11A          East      0       10.00
 USB     BBB          North     1       125.01
 USB     BBB          West      1       101.10
```

TABLE1 (show supplier with the cheapest price of the product, regardless of it being in stock or not -- WORKING)

```
CODE
======
SELECT a.name , a.partnumber , a.supplier , a.cost FROM table1 a JOIN (
SELECT name , partnumber , MIN(cost) cost
FROM table1 
GROUP BY name , partnumber ) 
b ON a.name = b.name AND a.cost = b.cost AND a.partnumber = b.partnumber


RESULT
======
|item   |partnumber  |supplier   |stock |cost 
 CD      11A          East        0      10.00
 USB     BBB          West        1      101.10
```

However, what I would like to achieve is:

IF a supplier is out of stock, then show the other supplier that has the product in stock, eventhough the price may not be the cheapest. (may be the 2nd cheapest, 3rd cheapest etc) - IF NO supplier has the item in stock, then show the supplier with the cheapest price regardless.

In short: Having item in stock takes precedence over price (however it still has to be the cheapest possible price for the item), but if no one has the item at all, then show the supplier that offered the item cheapest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  In other databases, you would use `row_number()`.  That is not an option in MySQL.

One method to do this uses variables.  Here is another method:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.supplier = (select tt1.supplier
                     from table1 tt1
                     where tt1.partnumber = t1.partnumber
                     order by (stock > 0) desc, -- put those with stock first
                              price asc
                     limit 1
                    );
```

The method using variables is:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             (@rn := if(@pn = partnumber, @rn + 1,
                        if(@pn := partnumber, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from table1 t1 cross join
           (select @pn := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by partnumber, (stock > 0) desc, price
     ) t1
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!